# What is the actual work of dopamine? Does it provide happiness or gives birth to desire?

Tags: dopamine, executive-function

As per my initial readings about [dopamine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine) are concerned it is usually stated that (like [here](https://www.longdom.org/open-access/happiness-role-of-dopamine-and-serotonin-on-mood-and-negative-emotions-2165-7548-1000350.pdf) )

> Dopamine is a hormone associated with happiness.

But today I have come across a [video](https://youtu.be/ukFjH9odsXw) in which the narrator says that dopamine may not be associated with happiness but gives birth to desires, beacuse addicts tends to indulge in activities which no longer provide them any happiness and even then they cannot stop.

So, what role does dopamine plays in addiction? Does it provide happiness or make us to do the “slavery” ?